# How to show/hide night mode overlay on MKMapView with respect to time

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am trying to add night mode overlays/markers etc... on MKMapView if the the specific day time is between night hours. The challenge is to add overlay or marker on specific locations where the current time is between night hours.

[image]

You can see the attached image. It shows different states of United States and a day slider widget on bottom. When I slide in,The date and time changes. I have to show night and day for selected time in slider on Map for different states...

When slider slides to night hours, Map should show animated night overlay from any (right/left) direction on the locations/states where time is between night hours.

**Tried approaches**

**First**

I m able to add a overlay on full map to show as nightMode this is how I tried. 
When slider time is between 19:00 to 07:00 I am adding a dark overlay on map.

```
func addNightModeOverLay()  {
    if (self.nightMode == nil){
        let mapRadius = CLLocationDistance(exactly: MKMapRectWorld.size.height)!
        self.nightMode = MKCircle(center: mapView.centerCoordinate, radius: mapRadius)
        self.mapView.add(nightMode!)
    }
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    if overlay.isKind(of: MKCircle.self) {
        let view = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        view.fillColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
        return view
    }
    return MKOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
}
```

When slider time is between 07:00 to 18:00 I am removing the dark overlay from map.

```
func removeNightModeOverLay()  {
    if let nightMode = self.nightMode {
        self.mapView.remove(nightMode)
        self.nightMode = nil
    }
}
```

It is simple on / off effect of dark layer overlay on map view.

**Second**

I also can add marker with custom image to full screen and animate this using `UIView.animate with duration` from source `Lat` `Lng` to destination `Lat` `Lng` but can not handle the animation direction and speed.

**Problems are**

1: Add night mode only on locations where there is night at selected time

2: Night overlay should come across on mapView animatedly as time changes between night and day.

I'm not sure how to get this result or even if there is a good way to achieve it. Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please tell me which dark overlay you are adding?

Answer (score 0):

For this you may use **Google Time Zone API**

You just need to give lat, lng to API.Response from API is

> {
>
> "dstOffset" : 3600,
>       "rawOffset" : -18000,
>       "status" : "OK",
>       "timeZoneId" : "America/New_York",
>       "timeZoneName" : `"Eastern Daylight Time"`
>
> }

Use "timeZoneName" value to turn off and on night mode

Comment: How it can describe the night hours of the selected/specific location?